# jquery refresh source code, but changes not shown in browser?

Tags: jquery, html, .refresh

I am trying to write a small form, in which I will have 3 radiobuttons with names of 3 different templates(text-files). If one is chosen, the content of the text-file should be shown in a textarea below, and when I choose another one, the content in the textarea should be updated. 
So far, everything is working, I can choose and change between the templates and the text will be updated. BUT, when I change text in a template and then choose another template, text in the textarea will not be updated. However when I view source code of the text area part, I can see its changing when I click another radiobutton, just not in browser(need to press F5).

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="packet_form">
...
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="tpl_name">Templates:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
        <?php
         /* get_tpl_array() returns an array with names from a directory, which is working fine */
         foreach (get_tpl_array() as $tpl_name)
         {
           echo '<div class="radio">';
           echo '<label>';
           echo '<input type="radio" name="tpl_name" id="'.$tpl_name .'" value="' . $tpl_name . '">' . $tpl_name;
           echo '</label>';
           echo '</div>';
         }
      ?>
       </div> //end col-xs-9
   </div> // end form-group
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-3 control-label" for="licence_text">Licence:>label>
      <div class="col-xs-9">
           <textarea class="form-control" id="licence_text" name="licence_text" rows="20">
           </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[name="tpl_name"]:radio').on("change", get_tpl_content);

   /* set the first option checked if none of the radiobuttons is checked */   
   if (!$('input[name="tpl_name"]:checked').val()) {
       $('input:radio:first').attr('checked', true);
       get_tpl_content();
   }

   function get_tpl_content() {
    var tpl_name = $("#packet_form input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    var name = {
        "tpl_name": tpl_name
    };
    if (name !== "") {
        var name_value = JSON.stringify(name);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Show_tpl_in_packet.php",
            data: {
                tpl: name_value
            },
            success: show_tpl_in_textarea
        });
    }
}

function show_tpl_in_textarea(content) {
    $("#licence_text").empty().append(content);
}
```

and here is my Show_tpl_in_packet.php:

```
require_once '/config/Config.php';

if ($_POST['tpl'])
{
    $json_tpl = json_decode($_POST['tpl']);
    $tpl_name = $json_tpl->tpl_name;
}
/* tpl_path is define in config.php as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . project_path . "/tpl/"  */
$file_path = tpl_path . $tpl_name . ".txt";
/* get text from file */
$template_content = file_get_contents($file_path);

echo $template_content;
```

I was thinking I should reload the page (which is strange because the text will be updated as long as I don't change it), and changed show_tpl_in_textarea funcion to

```
function show_tpl_in_textarea(content) {
   $("#licence_text").empty().append(content);
   location.reload();
}
```

but this results in a reload-loop. What do I do wrong?

Comment: I see nothing with the id of `packet_form` in your html

Comment: sry, its the id of the form, I forgot it when I post it here, its in my original code of course...

Comment: Also your quotes are messed up on this line: `echo '<input type="radio" name="tpl_name" id="'.$tpl_name".' value="' . $tpl_name . '">' . $tpl_name;` (after your id - closing quotes are the wrong way around)

Answer (score 0):

After reading through jquery-APIs and other similar questions, I finally found the mistake. For some reason, `.empty().append(content)` doesnt update the content if this is changed, neither do `.html()` or `.text()` (even when API says something else...). The only thing working is `.val(content)`.